# Gaussian integral with quadratic coefficients given by a non-symmetric complex matrix

Tags: complex-integration, gaussian-integral

If $A\in\operatorname{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$

We define $A_+$ as the complex symmetric part(not to be confused with Hermitian part):
$$A_+=\frac{A+A^T}{2}$$
and the antisymmetric part as
$$A_-=\frac{A-A^T}{2}$$
If the matrix $\operatorname{Re}A_+$ is positive definite, then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \! d^n x ~e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T A x} 
~=~ \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det A_+}}\tag{B}$$
Here, I am thinking if,
$$x^TA x=x^T\left(A_++A_-\right)x=x^TA_+x$$
where $$x^TA_-x=0$$
Is my line of reasoning correct ?
Then can I claim
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \! d^n x ~e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T A x+Bx} 
~=~ \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det A_+}}\tag{B}e^{\left(B^TA_+^{-1}B\right)}$$
where $B\in\operatorname{Mat}_{n\times 1}(\mathbb{C})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to prove that $x^TA_-x=0$. I will use the Einstien's summation convention where
\begin{align}
   x^TA_-x&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(A_-\right)_{ij}x_i x_j\\
&=\left(A_-\right)_{ij}x^ix^j
\end{align}
As $i$and $j$ are dummy variables, swapping $i$ and $j$ keeps keeps $x^TA_-x$ invariant, i.e,
\begin{align}
\left(A_-\right)_{ij}x^ix^j=\left(A_-\right)_{ji}x^jx^i
\end{align}

Since, $A_-$ is antisymmetric, $\left(A_-\right)_{ij}=-\left(A_-\right)_{ji}$ and that $x^ix^j=x^jx^i$
\begin{align}
   x^TA_-x&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(A_-\right)_{ij}x^i x^j+\left(A_-\right)_{ji}x^jx^i\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left\{\left(A_-\right)_{ij}-\left(A_-\right)_{ij}\right\}x^ix^j\right]\\
&=0
\end{align}